# MS Teams Sign in button showing multiple times

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams

I've developed a Microsoft Teams bot with the javascript SDK that incorporates a sign-in feature using the OAuth flow. However, I'm encountering an issue where the sign-in button appears multiple times within the chat interface, and upon clicking it, the authorization process doesn't initiate until the fourth attempt. This behavior is inconsistent and frustrating for users.

[Sign in button on teams](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2rKc3.png)

I've observed this behavior both during testing and in production environments. Despite clicking the sign-in button, the authorization process seems to only kick in after the fourth click. This issue is adversely impacting user experience and adoption of the bot.

To illustrate the problem, I have attached images showing the repetitive appearance of the sign-in button and the corresponding clicks required before successful authorization.

What could be causing this issue, and how can I rectify it to ensure the sign-in button functions reliably with a single click? Any insights or suggestions on debugging this problem would be greatly appreciated.
[network calls](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z61VL.png)

Comment: Could you please let us know if you are getting any console log?

Comment: I'm not receiving any console log

Comment: We tried with below sample(
https://github.com/OfficeDev/Microsoft-Teams-Samples/tree/main/samples/app-complete-auth/csharp
), however we are not able to repro this. Its working fine from our side